# Meteor Angular Tutorial: Todos List's <todos-list></todos-list> tag

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I am trying to go through Meteor's tutorial at https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/templates
There's a part that I can't figure out
in their client/main.js:

```
<body>
<div class="container" ng-app="simple-todos">
    <todos-list></todos-list>
</div>
</body>
```

They just put a `<todos-list>` tag in the middle and that template is loaded. I can't figure out how the todos-list gets translated to the actual template, is there some name transformation convention that "todos-list" gets translated to "todosList" and referenced that way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the Normalisation performed by AngularJS.

> **Normalization**
>
> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).
>
> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> 1. Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.
> 2. Convert the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.

Link to AngularJS Docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Thanks JeremyK, the docs helped explain all my doubts. Learning angular before going angular-meteor routes sounds like a correct way to go.

Comment: @RayLuo it absolutely is. Angular is a full-fledged framework, so look at the documentation and read up on it. If you found any answers helpful, please upvote them and accept the correct answer to reward folks for taking the time to answer your question.

Comment: @Yatrix Definitely, unfortunately I am a total newbie in StackOverflow, I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but I am working towards it. Thanks so  much for helping

Answer (score 1):

`todosList` is a component. Since html doesn't support capitalization, you write `todos-list` in the tag. A component can come with a template (html mark-up) associated with it. So, when you put `<todos-list></todos-list>` in your html, angular will insert the html there. Look at the angular documentation for components and directives. There are tons examples on the web.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out different terms here, I didn't even know to search for component for help docs.